# Alsa tools not found on buildroot

Tags: alsa, buildroot

I am trying to set a buildroot install to build an mp3 player and the issue I am encountering right now is that aplay that I have enabled in menuconfig is not available on my card flashed.

I am using buildroot-2020.02.8.

When looking for them in my BR folder I can find :

```
./build/alsa-utils-1.2.1/aplay
./build/alsa-utils-1.2.1/aplay/aplay
```

but nothing appears in the target. In my defconfig I have :

```
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSACONF=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ACONNECT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSALOOP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSAUCM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ALSATPLG=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_AMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_AMIXER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_APLAY=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_APLAYMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ARECORDMIDI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ASEQDUMP=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_ASEQNET=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_BAT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_IECSET=y
BR2_PACKAGE_ALSA_UTILS_SPEAKER_TEST=y
```

But in the target folder I can't find any mention of these tools. And when the card is flashed, trying to run any of these as root return "not found".

Any advice on what I sould do to try to get them?

edit: added the buildroot version used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320800/how-to-clean-only-target-in-buildroot) I have found a solution. It seems that is was because I had first tried to install only alsamixer (which was working), then later other alsa tools. The first configuration was kept in memory and not changed.

I have been able to fix the issue by running :

`make alsa-utils-dirclean`